# What is the difference between movies and films

Tags: analysis

The title speaks for itself. So often in discussions surrounding cinema, I see the words ‘film’ and ‘movie’ being used interchangeably. However, are the two really the same? I would appreciate it if you guys could explain it for me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a Movie question it's a **language** question

Answer (score 3):

Movie is the American word for film.

Film is the UK word for movie.

That simple.
One was named for the 'action' added to still photography, the other for the medium it was shot on. In those days the two countries, though they share a linguistic history, were really far apart in terms of new word coinage.*
As the world shrinks culturally, the words become more and more interchangeable.

*Consider another icon of the early 20th century - the car.. or automobile. The UK & USA never did agree on what to call all the bits, and to this day they remain separate. Boot/trunk; bonnet/hood; bumper/fender etc.